# Xamarin Forms: Android Phone contacts is not listing

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am referring to [this](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/10/10/getting-phone-contacts-in-xamarin-forms/) blog for listing the phone contacts. It is working fine on the ios part but on android part, the contacts are not listing. There are no exceptions or errors but the UI is blank.

As per the blog I have done the below things on the android platform:

1. created the model class **Contact** and interface **IContactsService.**
2. Added **READ_CONTACTS** permission and added **ContactsService** implementation.
3. Installed **Plugin.CurrentActivity** and **Acr.UserDialogs** packages.
4. Added **Permission.Util** class into the Android project.
5. Added required things on the **MainActivity** and **ContactPage** files on the Main project.

Don't know what I am missing on the android part, on ios it is working fine. On android, the contact permission is not asking during runtime. I manually add the permission from the app settings, but no luck. **My Xamarin forms version: 4.8.0.1821**

I am uploading a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1alyfrSuQ4a_xqCWDUora6AbXZN-sAYby/view?usp=sharing) for reference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got the answer from my Microsoft QA [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/417445/xamarin-forms-android-phone-contacts-is-not-listin.html):**

Android 10 does not use Android.Support.V4.Content.ContextCompat to request permission, so please use Xamarin.Essentials: Permissions to request runtime permission.

On ContactsViewModel.cs, add CheckAndContactsReadPermission()method in LoadContacts method like following code.

```
async Task LoadContacts()
    {
        try
        {
            await CheckAndContactsReadPermission();
            await _contactService.RetrieveContactsAsync();
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task was cancelled");
        }
    }
    public async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckAndContactsReadPermission()
    {
        var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.ContactsRead>();
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            return status;
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        {
            // Prompt the user to turn on in settings
            // On iOS once permission has been denied it may not be requested again from the application
            return status;
        }
       
        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.ContactsRead>();
        return status;
    }
```

On ContactsService.cs, change the LoadContactsAsync method like the following code.

```
async Task<IList<Contact>> LoadContactsAsync()
    {
        IList<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
        //var hasPermission = await RequestPermissionAsync();
        //if (hasPermission)
        //{
            var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;
            var ctx = Application.Context;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var cursor = ctx.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(uri, new string[]
                {
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoThumbnailUri
                }, null, null, $"{ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName} ASC");
                if (cursor.Count > 0)
                {
                    while (cursor.MoveToNext())
                    {
                        var contact = CreateContact(cursor, ctx);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contact.Name))
                        {
                            OnContactLoaded?.Invoke(this, new ContactEventArgs(contact));
                            contacts.Add(contact);
                        }
                        if (stopLoad)
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
       // }
        return contacts;
    }
```